# Owl Carousel - Click image for next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an owl carousel and want to get to the next image when I click on the image. No arrows or pagination, etc.

I do not have much experience with owl carousel.

This is what I have in my HTML. I set `touchDrag` equal to `true`, however I want a click on the image to advance to the next one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    //Carousel
    $(".carousel").owlCarousel({
        items : 1,
        autoPlay: true, 
        touchDrag  : true,
        mouseDrag  : true,    
        singleItem:true,
        responsive:true,
        autoHeight : true,
        transitionStyle:"fade"

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attach a click handler to the carousel slides themselves that moves it onto the next one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Carousel
  var owl = $(".carousel").owlCarousel({
    items : 1,
    autoPlay: true, 
    touchDrag  : true,
    mouseDrag  : true,    
    singleItem:true,
    responsive:true,
    autoHeight : true,
    transitionStyle:"fade"
  });

  $('.owl-item').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
  })
});
```

Comment: Adding link for related documentation: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: Its correct according to the docs and I had this running in a codepen. Pleas post generated html - and are you sure you are exposing the owl via var owl = ...

Comment: I've copied the whole code from you into my HTML which was looking like this previously;

<!-- CAROUSEL -->  
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Carousel
    $(document).ready(function(){
 "use strict";
 //Carousel
  $(".carousel").owlCarousel({
  items : 1,
  autoPlay: true, 
        touchDrag  : true,
        mouseDrag  : true,    
  singleItem:true,
  responsive:true,
  autoHeight : true,
  transitionStyle:"fade"
            
 });
});
</script>

Comment: Your issue is likely because you have multiple carousels on the page. for this to work, they would need to be referenced individually. i.e. var owl = $(".carousel-1") and $('.carousel-1 .owl-item')